# numpy nan in results without having nan in values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get `np.nan` values in my array when performing numpy calculation. `val.isna().values.any()` gives no `np.nan` but after calculation array holds `np.nan`.

Example:

```
delta_h = np.abs(start_height - end_height)
J_e = np.array([d / l if not np.isnan(d / l) else 0.002 for
                d, l in zip(delta_h, length)])
J_e = np.abs(J_e)
DN = np.abs(DN)

print("DN {}".format(DN.isna().values.any()))
print("J_E {}".format(np.isnan(J_e).any()))
print("J_E {}".format(J_e.isna().values.any()))

C = (np.pi * np.power(DN, 2)) / 4
     log = ((2.51 * v) / (DN * np.sqrt(2 * g * DN * J_e))) + (k / (3.71 * DN))
rot = 2 * g * DN * J_e

print("log {}".format(np.isnan(log).any()))
print("rot {}".format(np.isnan(rot).any()))

log10 = np.log10(log)
sqrt = np.sqrt(rot)

print("log10 {}".format(np.isnan(log10).any()))
print("sqrt {}".format(np.isnan(sqrt).any()))

t = -2 * log10

print("-2 * log10 {}".format(np.isnan(t).any()))

tt = -2 * sqrt

print("-2 * sqrt {}".format(np.isnan(tt).any()))

ttt = log10 * sqrt

print("ttt {}".format(np.isnan(ttt).any()))

#        for i, x in enumerate(ttt):
#            if np.isnan(x):
#                print(sqrt[i], log10[i])

N = -2 * np.multiply(log10, sqrt)

print(N[N==np.nan])
print("C {}".format(C.isna().values.any()))
print("N {}".format(N.isna().values.any()))

V = C * N

print("V {}".format(np.isnan(V).any()))
```

Gives:
DN False
J_E False
log False
rot False
log10 False
sqrt False
-2 * log10 False
-2 * sqrt False
ttt True
Series([], Name: DN, dtype: float64)
C False
N True
V True

Why is `-2 * np.multiply(log10, sqrt)` suddenly with `np.nans` in the result array?
Also `-2 * log10 * sqrt` results in `np.nan` in array.

Data come from `geopandas.DataFrame()`

Comment: It's possible that you're taking a logarithm of a 0 or a negative number. That will result in np.nan since its undefined. Maybe print out the actual result values in each of your steps.

Answer (score 0):

There was division by zero, that was not mentioned by compiler.
Strange that the steps between did not show the failure.